# CSS3 margins and 100% width/height declarations

Tags: html, css

I'm very surprised: there are tons of posts asking about 100% height situations, but the ones that include **margins* in the child element don't yield any workable responses.

Surely this is very common, no? I'm struggling with my margins causing the child element to overflow. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aPzq/) below.

My CSS is like so:

```
html, body {height:100%} // definitely doing that one for 100% height issues
div {
    box-sizing:border-box; // I like my box model consistent, need only webkit
}
#outer {
    border:1px solid #f00;
    position:absolute; // this is a requirement
    top:40px;
    left:12px;
    width:300px;
}
#inner {
    position:relative; // I'm really hoping to avoid absolute
    border:1px solid #0f0;
    margin:10px 20px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3aPzq/**

The prized question is: how to get the child element (green border) to properly be inline of its parent, with correct margins?

Comment: You mean like http://jsfiddle.net/3aPzq/2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use width 100% in the case, because width is calculated before apply the margin. So the inner div will have 300px width, and then 20px margin.

It's better to use only margin parameters:

```
#inner {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #0f0;
    margin:10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna have inner box stay inside the outer box, then i wouldn't use margin, instead i'll use padding

```
    #inner {
    position:relative; // I'm really hoping to avoid absolute
    border:1px solid #0f0;
    padding:10px 20px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```